# UseJwtBearerAuthentication failed: Unauthorized token and The signature is invalid

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

I am having a web api service and a web client application to access the web api. Both are registered on azure active directory.
However, when the web client application tried to access web api, I got :

```
ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error=\"invalid_token\", error_description=\"The signature is invalid
```

Then I checked the token on https://jwt.io/, it indeed showed "invalid signature". However, I have no idea what is wrong here.

Here is how I retrieved the token:

```
string authority = "https://login.windows.net/tenantid-log-number/oauth2/token";
string clientID = "83adf895-681a-4dd6-9dfb-2a1484dd4188";

string resourceUri = "https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/webapiservice";
string appKey = "anJxg3N/5dqiHKx+4zwzFB9A6dN5HdqSitdSOpxzVd="; 

ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientID, appKey);

AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
Task<AuthenticationResult> authResult = ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientCredential);
return authResult.Result.AccessToken;
```

Here is how I access web api service:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://webapiservice.azurewebsites.net/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/values").Result;
```

Here is how web api service validates the access:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
     AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
     AutomaticChallenge = true,

     TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
     {
          ValidateAudience = true,
          ValidAudience = "https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/webapiservice",
      }
  });
```

Anything wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Not completely sure if this will help so I will add the following as a comment. I don't see that you are setting the audience nor the authority in the web api, see a sample here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-getting-started/blob/master/README.md. Also, jwt.io will not validate the token signature unless you follow this steps http://nzpcmad.blogspot.com.ar/2016/08/oauth2-verifying-azure-ad-jwt-signature.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your configuration and code snippets, it look like you're trying to setup a Web API for .Net Core using the Azure AD v1 endpoint.

**For .Net Core using the Azure AD v1 endpoint, you should use `UseJwtBearerAuthentication`** as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // ...
    // Other stuff
    // ...

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            Authority = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/", 
                Tenant),
            Audience = ClientId
        });
}
```

---

*For reference, here are some other setups that can be used:*

For .Net using the Azure AD v1 endpoint, you should use `UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication`

Here's a snippet from the official [.NET Web API sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet), sample that showcases how to set this up:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Audience = ClientId,
            Tenant = Tenant
        });
}
```

For .Net using the Azure AD v2 endpoint, you should use `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication` as follows:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    TokenValidationParameters tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        // Accept only those tokens where the audience of the token is equal to the client ID of this app
        ValidAudience = ClientId
    };

    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        // This SecurityTokenProvider fetches the Azure AD B2C metadata & signing keys from the OpenIDConnect metadata endpoint
        AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(String.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", Tenant)))
    });
}
```

For .Net Core using the Azure AD v2 endpoint, you should use `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // ...
    // Other stuff
    // ...

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            Authority = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0/", 
                Tenant),
            Audience = ClientId
        });
}
```

Comment: .net core does not support UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication directly.

Comment: Thanks Saca for taking time to answer my question. But .net core does not have "ConfigureAuth" function. Instead, .net core only has "Configure" and its parameter is "IApplicationBuilder" instead of "IAppBuilder".  So your updated answer still cannot work in .core net.

Comment: ConfigureAuth is just part of a pattern where a helper method is created for all auth stuff. You can do the same things that are being done there inside of the Configure method.

Comment: IApplicationBuilder does not have a method "UseJwtBearer".

Comment: Argh sorry, typo, it's "UseJwtBearerAuthentication", I updated the answer. Apologies.

Comment: It works perfectly! I do appreciate your help. One last question: do you know how to get ClaimsPrincipal after authentication went through? I tried to retrieve "ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope").Value" it crashed.

Comment: it turns out "ClaimsPrincipal.Current" is empty. In this case, I am not sure whether this can be claimed a successful authentication.

Comment: HttpContext.User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope")?.Value